# Remove a span implemented in first toggle using second toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble removing a span that is created on the first click in the toggle and removed on the second click of the toggle.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("td").toggle(
    function(){
        var current = $("input[name=prices]:checked").val();
        $(this).html("<img src='images/1.gif'/>");
        $(".summary").append("<br><span class = 'newticket' id = 'null'>");
        $("#null").attr("id",$(this).attr("id"));
        $(".summary").append("1 x ");
        if(current == 'full'){
            $(".summary").append("full price ticket.");
        }
        $(".summary").append(" Seat: ");
        $(".summary").append($(this).attr("id"));
        if(current == 'full'){
            $(".summary").append(" Price: £10</span>");
        }

    },
    function(){
        $(this).html("<img src='images/a.gif'/>");
        $("span#" + $(this).attr("id")).remove();
});
});
```

If i click on the table value the span is added however if i click again on the table value the span is not removed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When acting on elements that weren't present on DOM ready, you need to use on(): http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

You should not append unclosed tags 
create a string then append it.
Complete solution.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("td").toggle(
        function(){
            var current = $("input[name=prices]:checked").val();
            $(this).html("<img src='images/1.gif'/>");
            var html = "<br><span class = 'newticket' id = 'null'>";
            htnl += "1 x ";
            if(current == 'full'){ 
                html +="full price ticket.";
            }
           html +=" Seat: " + $(this).attr("id");
            $(".summary").append($(this).attr("id"));
            if(current == 'full'){
                 html +=" Price: £10"
            }

            html += "</span>";
            $(".summary") .append(html);   
        },
        function(){
            $(this).html("<img src='images/a.gif'/>");
            $(".summary span.newticket").remove();
    });

});
```